# Prevent jQueryUI Tabs from Showing Unmodified HTML

Tags: jquery-ui

A page that's using jQueryUI Tabs sometimes displays the original markup, before being modified to tabs:

[image]

When I see this, it shows up for estimated 0.2 - 1.0 seconds.

How can I prevent the original markup from showing?

Comment: honestly i have seen this happen often and I think it depends on the browser some browser load the page and then it takes like maybe a sec for jquery ui to take effect I can only recommend to find a way to increase the loading of the script or maybe get the script loaded before the page loads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That stuff is called FOUC (Flash of Unstyled Content). The solution to this is to hide the div that contains that tabs using css and displaying it back using javascript After the entire page is loaded.

```
$(window).load(function () {
   $('#your-tabbed-bar-div').show();
});
```

More info can be found here:
http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/
http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is some javascript that is executing before the jquery ui stuff, so could it be as simple as rearranging the order of your js tags?

If that's not going to work I would suggest a hack - make sure the styles get loaded onto the page, if the file is not downloading fast enough, which is doubtful since the browser is going to most likely cache the file and which probably isn't very big to begin with - anyway, you could copy the styles and make sure they get loaded quickly, and then set the class attributes of the list elements specifically in the html.

If you don't like that hack, what about this one - set the list style to display:none, then run use setTimeout to keep checking for the style property you want to see - when it's there, set the display of the to block (or whatever) and of course stop checking for the attribute after you see it.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [jQuery UI documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...prevent_a_FOUC_.28Flash_of_Unstyled_Content.29_before_tabs_are_initialized).

Comment: That documentation refers to adding a style to the DIV's that make up the panels.  The part that's flashing are the UL/LI's that make up the tabs themselves...